# string to total_seconds in a dataframe column HH:MM:SS.f

Tags: python-3.x

In Python 3.7 I'd like to change the string data in a column called 'TIME' to `total_seconds()`. Using `ax1.dt.total_seconds()` however I'm receiving the ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format

This is the column in the dataframe ax1 as it currently stands:-

[image: TIME column]

I've tried the following code:-

```
ax1['TIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(ax1['TIME'])
ax1.dt.total_seconds()
ax1.map('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my own question.

I added

```
ax1['TIME'] = '00:' + ax1['TIME'].astype(str)
```

To get HH:MM:SS.f from the existing MM:SS.f format.

I then ran:-

```
ax1['TIME']=pd.to_timedelta(ax1['TIME'], unit= 'ms') 
ax1['TIME_delta_secs']=ax1['TIME'].dt.total_seconds()
```

The `unit` was the key part that was missing from my original question.

As the time didn't start from Zero.

```
#Finds 0
if any(dfs[i]['TIME_delta_secs'] == 0):
    Zero_time = dfs[i][dfs[i]['TIME_delta_secs'] == 0].index.values[0]
    dfs[i].loc[dfs[i].index[Zero_time:],"Time_delta_secs"] = dfs[i]['TIME_delta_secs'] + 3600
else:
    pass

    
# Time difference

dfs[i]["time_diff"] = (dfs[i]['TIME_delta_secs']-dfs[i]['TIME_delta_secs'].shift(1))
dfs[i]['time_diff'] = dfs[i]['time_diff'].fillna(0)

# Total running Time 

dfs[i]['Time_total'] = dfs[i]['time_diff'].cumsum()
```

`cumsum()` was the key part that got a total running time.

Hope this helps others. Thanks